# Leaflet in RStudio: content is static for RHTML documents, dynamic for RMarkdown

Tags: r, leaflet, knitr

I'm trying to create some maps using leaflet in RStudio. I can get the dynamic maps working when I knit a RMarkDown document such as:

````
---
title: "Map00"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## A Map

```{r}
library(leaflet)
m <- leaflet()
m <- addTiles(m)
m <- addMarkers(m, lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m
```
````

But when I knit a RHTML version of the same map such as (same R code, just pasted it into boilerplate RHTML template):

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Map01</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--begin.rcode fig.width=7, fig.height=6
library(leaflet)
m <- leaflet()
m <- addTiles(m)
m <- addMarkers(m, lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m
end.rcode-->

</body>
</html>
```

I get a static version of the map.

The HTML files generated are also very different: the Markdown version generates for me a 1.2Mb file, with javascript on it. The HTML version just points to a local file in the `figure` folder.

I guess it is an issue with knit -- any hints on how to solve it?

thanks

Comment: what is your ideal outcome? The Knit>Rmd approach looks like it is still generating a HTML file (albeit with more bells and whistles), while the HTML notebook is more barebones. My understanding is the you *can* add JS/CSS/anything to HTML notebooks but you must do it explicit (eg load the leaflet js lib) whereas knitting builds a much richer web environment by default

Comment: @Nate I use those for lecture notes. I got used to create RHTML documents instead of RMD ones, then some includes on the RHTML I was able to customize them with CSS. Note that these are not raw HTML documents, as per the examples.  I just got surprised that knitting RMD to HTML gives very different results from knitting RHTML to HTML.

Comment: Apparently knitting RMD to HTML includes all JS libraries, while knitting RHTML to HTML does not.